# Workaround for blocked external database connection

Tags: mysql

I'm currently working on a booking system for some student cabins. Due to some security issues, we had to move the site from the university server over to an external server. The problem is that we have to connect to a database on the university server to get the login credentials for the users (There are different sites using the same database for user validation), and it seems to block outside connections. Are there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Asking the Uni server admins to allow connections from the new server's IP is the easiest way that comes to mind.

If that isn't an option, you'd have to start creating a PHP script on the Uni server that looks up the required data, and serves it to the script running on your external server... But that necessitates fundamental changes in the way your software works.

Another idea is mirroring the credentials frequently between Server A and Server B, e.g. using a Cron job.

Comment: I have already sent an email to the server admins, but I guess they are pretty rigid when it comes to such things.
I only use the database connection one place in my code, and that is for validation of every login. To you have any pointers as how I should proceed in order to creating such a solution as you are describing?

Comment: @Øyvind You'd have to do a request to a PHP file on the uni server instead (which is slowwww...) and have that PHP file fetch the data you need (because it can access the database). You would pass it a user record's ID, for example; it would look up the ID and return the credentials - for example in JSON encoding. But as said, that's very slow. Have you considered mirroring the login data to the external server instead? Like, doing an upload every 24 hours or so?

Comment: I've considered to copy everything over to the new database, but it has to be updated a lot to keep them both consistent. There are new users who register all the time, and also password changes from time to time. I guess the last solution would be to force the users to register at the booking system.

Comment: @Øyvind yeah, that sounds difficult. Although you might be able to run a job every 15 minutes, see whether anything has changed, and upload only if it has... If the registrations and password changes have time stamps, of course.

Comment: Well, thx for the answers. I guess I will wait for an answer from the admins, which probably won't come until monday :) Fingers crossed!